# Return minimum X (that can contain Y items) for arbitrary number of items

Tags: php, python, math

*Feeling pretty brain-dead right now.* I can, of course, brute-force this, but I feel like there *has* to be a simple function to return this number. Concerning native functions, I'm using PHP and/or Python.

For example: there exists containers that hold **X** (5) breadsticks each, and 
I need to feed **Y** (25) people **Z** (3) breadsticks each.

I need to return the number of containers I have to acquire to feed these people. (There may or may not be remainder breadsticks).

**EDIT:** Clarified some intention.

Comment: By brute force you mean (Y * Z) / X? What have you tried?

Comment: I realize that the title and example algebra do not match. Hope that's not too distracting. If I knew what this operation was called (to put it in the title) I would have had my way with Google already. =/

Comment: By "brute-force" I mean a loop, in which the number of containers is increased until there is a remainder, or some such. I hadn't even tried ceil. I should probably not be programming today. This is sick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, use `//` (integer floor division, introduced in Python 2.2) and force it to round up:

```
number_required = y * z
container_holds = x
reqd_containers = (number_required + container_holds - 1) // container_holds
```

or if you require the so-called "professional programmer" version instead of the explanatory version:

```
n=(y*z+(x-1))//x;
```

or if you are really afraid of carpal tunnel syndrome, chop the two redundant parentheses and the semicolon:

```
n=(y*z+x-1)//x
```

**Note: this solution works on both Python 2 (where `10 / 3 -> 3`) and Python 3 (where `10 / 3 -> 3.3333333333333335`)**

Other "solutions" not only use unnecessary function calls but also fail with large numbers:

```
# wrong in Python 3; works with Python 2.3 to 2.7
# int overflow with Pythons up to 2.2
>>> int((100000000000000000 + 2)/3)
33333333333333332 # last digit should be 4

# wrong with Python 2.3 onwards; int overflow with earlier versions
>>> import math
>>> int(math.ceil(float(100000000000000000) / 3))
33333333333333332L
```

Comment: -1, too verbose.  Carpal tunnel is a very real danger for professional programmers.

Comment: @ John, thanks, this returns the correct result. Sorry about the dumb question. Is there a mathematical term for what I'm trying to achieve here? Something along the lines of "GCD/LCD", etc?

Comment: @anonymous coward: term is "ceiling function" ...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want arithmetic:

```
min_containers = y*z/x
```

If you have situations that may give a remainder:

```
min_full_containers = floor(y*z/x)
remaining_items = y*z%x
```

Comment: On the first couple tries, it seems that this gives 1-too-few containers. I may not have been clear enough about my intention with "full containers". I will edit the question.

Comment: Then do ceiling(y*z/x). You did ask for full containers, if you have remaining pieces, you will need a partially filled container, so ceiling is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(X, Y, Z):
  d, r = divmod(Y * Z, X)
  return d + bool(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#python
import math

int(math.ceil(float(Y) * Z / X))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ned's answer is correct.  It is also common to avoid the function call overhead to math.ceil() by doing the following:

```
minContainers = int((y*z+(x-1))/x);
```

Comment: -1 It's unfortunately all too common to muck about with floating point for an integer-only problem.

Comment: Please don't neg comments unless they are wrong.  My answer is correct.

Comment: If you're referring to Ned's post, yes, it wastes time.  You'll note though that my solution is the same as yours in three lines of code instead of one.  I'm not sure ow do you figure it "mucks about with floating point"?  There's only integer math going on there.

Comment: @par: 3 lines of code was to give explanation instead of the x,y,z. Not same. In Python 3, `int` / `int` => `float`. My solution works for both Python 2 and Python 3. If you think there's only integer math, you don't need the `int()`.

Comment: int/int = float.  Now your criticism makes sense, I've got a C background not Python so that's an unexpected implicit typecast for me.  The int() cast was to show the OP that's what is intended.  The double-slash floor truncation operator is handy but looks like a C++ comment to me ;)

Answer (score -1):

($people * $breadSticksPerPerson) / $holders isn't correct?

EDIT: Sorry, misread your question, posted the correct solution in comments

Comment: In this case, I am determining `$holders`, it is not yet known.

Comment: Oh, in that case, it would be $holders = ($people * $breadsticksPerPerson) / BREADSTICKS_PER_HOLDER;

Comment: -1 This can be correct only if PHP integer division rounds up.